# How to draw a pressure gauge in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm wondering if anyone can help me out with some Canvas. I'm pretty new to it, so stay with me. I have this pressure gauge [image] and I want to animate the red needle in canvas (in my application I photoshoped the needle out, and redrew it with canvas). Ideally, I'd like it to pass it an angle, and it would move from where ever it is to the new angle I pass (either move clockwise or counter clockwise) I can also pass it another variable to tell it which way to go.

My original idea was to pass it a pressure 0-600, and figure out what the ratio was between 1 psi and 1 degree. But it wasn't too exact and so it didn't work.

I'm wondering what the next thing to do would be... I'm hoping someone could help me recreate this gauge in canvas, numbers, tic marks and needle. This way The ratio between angle and psi would be exact and I would know how many PSI = 1 degree.

My other problem is getting it to animate. I have it animating, if I pass in an end angle, and a start angle. I'd rather pass in just a single pressure and it would move from where it is, to the new angle.

Here is the code I have: http://jsfiddle.net/vPu3U/1/
(sorry about the messy code, i'm still trying to figure out canvas)

Thanks!!

Edit: I think I'm at the point now where I figured out the animation. My main goal now is to figure out the tic marks. Once I get those equally spaced looking similar to the picture, I'll probably be able to figure out the needle and I pretty much have the animation down. And since all the tic marks are the same distance from each other I could figure out the ratio between each tic mark (Angle) and PSI. So really it's just drawing the semi circle with tic marks and numbers. Thanks!

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rotating an offset needle:
http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_gauge.html

Drawing tic marks in a ring:
http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html

Comment: Yea... that's showing the needle and animating it. I already have that part. I'm more looking for how to make the tic marks and the actual gauge.

Comment: @Bill I've edited my answer with another demo that daws tic marks. It sounds like you are asking someone to do your work for you. Do you have a specific problem you need help with, other than "all of it"?

Comment: I'm really more just looking to draw the tick marks with the numbers inside. Once I get those equally spaced looking similar to the picture, I'll probably be able to figure out the needle and I pretty much have the animation down. And since all the tic marks are the same distance from each other I could figure out the ratio between each tic mark (Angle) and PSI. So really it's just drawing the semi circle with tic marks and numbers. Thanks!

Comment: @bill Sadly i am typing one-handed right now on an iPad (recovering from shoulder surgery) so I can't write a full custom example for you. Hopefully my second link above shows how to rotate the ticks. As for the text, you'll just need to do some trigonometry and/or tweaking. Good Luck!